# AJAX load title of multiple span.has-tip elements that may have different IDs to query

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, properties, attributes

For every `span.has-tip` I want to grab an identifier, then load the corresponding content via ajax from a glossary page into the title attr of the span. I'm using pieces of Zurb's Foundation on the site, so I decided to go with their http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/tooltips.html for presentation.

I'll just pseudocode what I want done:

```
for each element that has the class has.tip 
take the value of the attribute data-tooltip
pass it as a filter/parameter to target/parse an id on the page /documentation/glossary/
take the contents of that id and put them in the title of the element
move to next element
```

Sample page source:

`Yo, <span data-tooltip="base-view" class="has-tip" title="">Base View</span> is bar bar.`

Sample data on /documentation/glossary/:

`<dd id="base-view">foo foo</dd>`

I want to end up with:

`Yo, <span data-tooltip="base-view" class="has-tip" title="foo foo">Base View</span> is bar bar.`

Note this needs to work with multiple span.has-tip with different data-tooltip values, and corresponding IDs on the glossary page.

I successfully inserted the content I wanted into the `span.tooltip` generated by Foundation, but this required hovering on and off the `span.has-tip` to be displayed. Not so ideal. Loading content into an attribute or property is more complex so I'm fumbling with callbacks, not being able to concat .load at certain times, [object Object] returns and whatnot. :)

**update:** FYI Foundation Tooltip returns (for this example) `<span data-selector="base-view" class="tooltip" style="FOOBARS"><span class="nub"></span></span>`. Source for this plugin is @ `github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/js/foundation/foundation.tooltip.js`

Non working example on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/erutan/HB98K/2/

Comment: just to be sure, you want the title to be displayed without hovering? (i got all the rest of it.)

Comment: Yes, I want the title in the span.has-tip without hovering, thanks!

Once it's in there, on hover it'll be called by Foundation for the fancy tooltip (not featured here). If I add the title on hover to has.tip, it doesn't get loaded into .tooltip that Foundation creates on hover, and just kludging it into .tooltip is straightforward but less than ideal.

Comment: does this fancy tooltip requires you to store the hover data ONLY in title attribute? i just not familiar with the plugin due to the fact you haven't told anyone what plugin it is.

Comment: Just got a ping with there is a pull request on Foundation that might make this easier: https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/3796

Comment: To clarify, I'm not worrying about the styling/behaviour of the tooltip itself, I just want to get the content into the title attribute. Once it's there (without firing hover), .each()? things will work. Once the pseudocode is good the rest should follow, I've tested it with static content in the title attr.